# Replace repeated values in collection with its sum

Tags: c#, list, linq, ienumerable

I have a list of custom class `ModeTime`, its structure is below:

```
private class ModeTime
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string LineName { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
}
```

In this list I have some items, whose `LineName` and `Mode`are the same, and they are written in the list one by one. I need to sum `Time` property of such items and replace it with one item with sum of `Time` property without changing `LineName` and `Mode`, `Date` should be taken from first of replaced items. I will give an example below:

```
Original:                                   Modified:
Date       | LineName | Mode   | Time               Date | LineName | Mode   | Time
01.09.2018 | Line1    | Auto   | 00:30:00     01.09.2018 | Line1    | Auto   | 00:30:00
01.09.2018 | Line2    | Auto   | 00:10:00     01.09.2018 | Line2    | Auto   | 00:15:00
01.09.2018 | Line2    | Auto   | 00:05:00     01.09.2018 | Line2    | Manual | 00:02:00
01.09.2018 | Line2    | Manual | 00:02:00     01.09.2018 | Line2    | Auto   | 00:08:00
01.09.2018 | Line2    | Auto   | 00:08:00     01.09.2018 | Line1    | Manual | 00:25:00
01.09.2018 | Line1    | Manual | 00:25:00     01.09.2018 | Line2    | Auto   | 00:24:00
01.09.2018 | Line2    | Auto   | 00:05:00     02.09.2018 | Line1    | Auto   | 00:05:00
02.09.2018 | Line2    | Auto   | 00:12:00
02.09.2018 | Line2    | Auto   | 00:07:00
02.09.2018 | Line1    | Auto   | 00:05:00
```

I have tried to write method to do it, it partly works, but some not summarized items still remain.

```
private static List<ModeTime> MergeTime(List<ModeTime> modeTimes)
{
    modeTimes = modeTimes.OrderBy(e => e.Date).ToList();
    var mergedModeTimes = new List<ModeTime>();

    for (var i = 0; i < modeTimes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i - 1 != -1)
        {
            if (modeTimes[i].LineName == modeTimes[i - 1].LineName &&
                modeTimes[i].Mode == modeTimes[i - 1].Mode)
            {
                mergedModeTimes.Add(new ModeTime
                {
                    Date = modeTimes[i - 1].Date,
                    LineName = modeTimes[i - 1].LineName,
                    Mode = modeTimes[i - 1].Mode,
                    Time = modeTimes[i - 1].Time + modeTimes[i].Time
                });
                i += 2;
            }
            else
            {
                mergedModeTimes.Add(modeTimes[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mergedModeTimes.Add(modeTimes[i]);
        }
    } 

    return mergedModeTimes;
}
```

I have also tried to wrap `for` with `do {} while()` and reduce source list `modeTimes` length. Unfortunately it leads to loop and memory leak (I waited till 5GB memory using).

Hope someone can help me. I searched this problem, in some familiar cases people use `GroupBy`. But I don't think it will work in my case, I must sum item with the same `LineName` and `Mode`, only if they are in the list one by one.

Comment: NEVER, NEVER, NEVER increment an index count inside a for loop (i += 2;).   Instead use a while loop.  You should of incremented by one instead of two because the for loop count also increments by 1 so you are incrementing by three instead of two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most primitive solution would be something like this.

```
var items = GetItems();
var sum = TimeSpan.Zero;

for (int index = items.Count - 1; index > 0; index--)
{
    var item = items[index];
    var nextItem = items[index - 1];

    if (item.LineName == nextItem.LineName && item.Mode == nextItem.Mode)
    {
        sum += item.Time;
        items.RemoveAt(index);
    }
    else
    {
        item.Time += sum;
        sum = TimeSpan.Zero;
    }
}
items.First().Time += sum;
```

Edit: I missed last line, where you have to add leftovers. This only applies if first and second elements of the collection are *the same*. Without it, it would not assign aggregated time to first element.

Comment: Thanks, this might works. I will test it and give feedback later.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I didn't notice that. On test db it works great. Why do you use reversed for here?

Comment: @QuarK Because I remove items. If I were to use normal `for` I would have to decrement `index`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ's `GroupBy`. To group only consecutive elements, this uses a trick. It stores the key values in a tuple together with a group index which is only incremented when `LineName` or `Mode` changes.

```
int i = 0; // Used as group index.
(int Index, string LN, string M) prev = default; // Stores previous key for later comparison.
var modified = original
    .GroupBy(mt => {
        var ret = (Index: prev.LN == mt.LineName && prev.M == mt.Mode ? i : ++i,
                   LN: mt.LineName, M: mt.Mode);
        prev = (Index: i, LN: mt.LineName, M: mt.Mode);
        return ret;
    })
    .Select(g => new ModeTime {
        Date = g.Min(mt => mt.Date),
        LineName = g.Key.LN,
        Mode = g.Key.M,
        Time = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(mt => mt.Time.Ticks))
    })
    .ToList();
```

This produces the expected 7 result rows.

Comment: Does it break original order order of list's items? I cann't do it, because it is switch between states of production line in technological process.

Comment: This groups by `Date`, `LineName` and `Mode` and sums the times. If you need a specific order, you can add a `OrderBy`.

Comment: Well, then It looks like you only want to group consecutive items.

Comment: Updated my answer completely to group only consecutive elements.